# Launch Windows Phone 8 Emulator programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

How to launch Windows Phone 8 Emulator programmatically from a desktop app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your Emulator launcher in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0 but the real problem isnt finding the program or even launching it pragmatically. The problem is that I think it needs a XAP file or it will not launch. If you can find a way to launch it however I think the easiest way would be from a .bat file

Open notepad
-type in cd  
Go to next line
-type executable name

Save as "fileName.bat"

MAKE SURE TO INCLUDE THE QUOTATIONS WHEN YOU SAVE or it will save it as a text file and not a batch
Double click it

Answer (score 1):

You may use the **Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity** API to launch the Windows Phone 8 Emulator from your program code. 
For further information, please see the Microsoft MSDN article: [Controlling Devices with the Smart Device Connectivity API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384093%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of launching the Emulator is From the Start Panel --> Hyper-V Virtual Machine a box will pop up with the list of Virtual Machines on your computer choose the Windows Phone Virtual Machine you have on your computer and click on OK your Windows Phone emulator will launch.